# Marching squares and encapsulated contours

Tags: image-processing, marching-cubes

Here's an image:

[image]

Can one, using the **marching squares** algorithm, write a program that given an input image like above, produces the following output:

**Two** chained line segments, one forming the above contours (hill-like), the other one forming the encapsuled circle contour?

If not, how else would you recommend doing it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232672/drawing-isotherm-linesor-contour-using-java-given-specific-points
if u ve gotten the answer then please help here.

Answer (score 1):

If the *marching squares* algorithm is like *marching cubes*, it will give you both contour lines.

You can also just subtract neighboring pixels from each other (see: edge detection), if the example image is representative of your images, that you want to process.